# How to create pods that can be install via cocoapods in swift

Tags: ios, swift, github, cocoapods

Actually i have created pod and also published on cocoapods but i came here for solution that i want is i want to create one framework instead of open code.

So,when developer install my pods developer can use my code but can't see my code and also cant change anything in my code.

Installed pod looks like just framework developer don't able to see code.

As i have seen one tutorial about my question but there is one step where we have to create zip and than upload to git and i follow it but after that step i am not able to configure .podspec file as from zip command can't find other files available.

I am mentioning url of that tutorial also please see it.

[Hide implementation of swift framework when distributing](https://crafttang.com/2017/10/12/hide-implementation-of-swift-framework-when-distri/)

I am here also showing you error that i am getting while try to check for issue on terminal.

```
- WARN  | source: The version should be included in the Git tag.
- ERROR | [iOS] file patterns: The `vendored_frameworks` pattern did not match any file.
- WARN  | [iOS] license: Unable to find a license file
- NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using new build system
- NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Planning build
- NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Constructing build description
- NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Execution policy exception registration f
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: in podspec set tag if it is not set, same tag should be on your branch in git - `git tag 1.0.6`

Comment: I have set tag as my branch name

Comment: s.source = {:git => 'https://github.com/xxxxxxxxx/Test3.git', :tag => 'master' }  @AlexandrKolesnik

Comment: now you have to add tag 'master' to your branch, but using string is a bad idea, look through the manual https://medium.com/@shahabejaz/create-and-distribute-private-libraries-with-cocoapods-5b6507b57a03

Comment: i have created branch on my repository and uploaded library in that branch only. @AlexandrKolesnik